# excel working with functions returning an array

Tags: arrays, excel

I have 3 cells that contain fruits:

```
banana
pear
apple
```

I added a name range to these cells: fruits.

In cell A1 I have the following string:
Banana, Book, Blue

If I use the search function in the following way
=search(fruits,A1)

it will return an array: {1,#value!, #value!}

What formula can I use in order to find out what is the position of 1 in the array (the non error value)?
In other words, I want to use =search(fruits,A1) as an argument in a formula that will return the position of the non error value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if below formula helps:

`=LOOKUP(COUNTA(fruits)+1,SEARCH(fruits,A1),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(fruits))))`

where

`COUNTA(fruits)+1` ensures that LOOKUP value is higher than count of fruits by 1.

`SEARCH(fruits,A1)` Your posted formula

`ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(fruits)))` generates an array of index positions starting from 1,2,3...

**Edit:**

Following adjustment shall help to get proper results

`=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(fruits,A1),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(fruits))))`

We try to get reciprocal where array `fruits` returns a match.

In rest of the cases, it'd return #VALUE error which `LOOKUP` manages to ignore. And since the returned position is always going to be 1 or greater than 1, `COUNTA(fruits)+1` part has no significance and therefore we can replace it with simple hard coded value 2.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working only for this input. But if I change A1 to 'Ford, yellow, pear', I get an error, while I am expecting to get the result 2, because the string contains 'pear', which is the second in the array of fruits.

Comment: @Hana thanks for pointing this out. I should've tested my formula before posting. I have addressed this, please see formula posted post-edit.

Comment: thanks! It works now. One more question. What if I want to return the actual value, not the position? I tried to remove the row function above and only use the index, but didn't work. I can put the entire thing above within another index faction like this: =INDEX(Fruits,LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(Fruits,A2),INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(Fruits)))) and it will work, but I assume it can be shorter?

Comment: @Hana you need to use `=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(fruits,A1),fruits)`. Have not tested it but it should work.